# Подскажите плагины/библиотеки для работы с NuxtJS 3 версии | Tell me plugins/libraries for working with NuxtJS 3 versions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, ckeditor

Всем привет, мучаюсь 3й день, не могу найти подходящие библиотеки для **NuxtJS 3** версии.

Подскажите пожалуйста модули по аналогии **DataTables** и **CKEditor**, которые могут работать с **NuxtJS 3 версии**.

Пробовал разные совместить с **3 Nuxt**, но безуспешно...

> Hello everyone, I'm suffering for the 3rd day, I can't find suitable
> libraries for **NuxtJS 3 versions**.
>
> Please tell me modules similar to **DataTables** and **CKEditor** that can
> work with **NuxtJS 3 versions**.
>
> I tried to combine different ones with **3 Nuxt**, but without success...

Comment: Вам нужно искать библиотеки не только для Nuxt 3. Если вы не находите библиотеку для Nuxt 3, попробуйте поискать библиотеку для Vue 3. Nuxt реализован поверх Vue. По CKEditor могу подсказать альтернативу, которую мы успешно интегрировали на нашем Nuxt 3 проекте: `Quill Editor` для Vue 3